# プログラミング　同じ処理

Tags: python, プログラミング言語

タイトルについて質問です。
例えば以下の情報をprint文で出力するとします。

```
犬は朝起きる
犬は昼ごはん食べる
犬は夜ご飯食べる
犬は寝る

猫は朝起きる
猫は昼ごはん食べる
猫は夜ご飯食べる
猫は寝る
```

犬というクラスと、猫というクラスがあります。　
「朝起きる」「昼ごはんたべる」等というメソッドがあり、その中でprint文を出力します。

犬と猫ともに、ふるまいは全く同じですが、出力するものが違います。これについて、何か効率的な処理はあるでしょうか？
言語は、Pythonで考えていただければ大変助かります。

お手数ですがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: タイトルは単語を並べるだけではなくて、質問内容が伝わるようなものを心がけてください。

Comment: 「Python オブジェクト指向 継承 多態性」などをキーワードにしてググるといろいろ参考になりそうな記事がヒットしますのでまずは自分で調べてみませんか。

Answer (score 2):

既に
オブジェクト指向
継承
などの用語が出ているので、それで解決していると思いますが。

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def wakeup(self):
        print(f"{self.name} wakeup.")

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("dog")
    
my_dog = Dog()
my_dog.wakeup()
del my_dog
```

Answer (score 1):

効率的かどうかは分かりませんが、`dataclass` を使うのもよいかと思います。

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class OneDay(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod # forbid instantiate
    def __init__(self): pass

    @classmethod
    def do_action(cls, action='何もしない'):
        if cls != __class__:
            print(f'{cls.__name__}は{action}')

methods = ['朝起きる', '昼ごはん食べる', '夜ご飯食べる', '寝る']
for m in methods:
    setattr(OneDay, m, classmethod(lambda cls,m=m: cls.do_action(action=m)))
del methods

@dataclass
class 犬(OneDay): pass

@dataclass
class 猫(OneDay): pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    犬.朝起きる()
    犬.昼ごはん食べる()
    犬.夜ご飯食べる()
    犬.寝る()
    犬.do_action(action='駆け回る')

    猫.朝起きる()
    猫.昼ごはん食べる()
    猫.夜ご飯食べる()
    猫.寝る()
    猫.do_action(action='炬燵で丸くなる')
```